# difference in array declaration and array memory allocation for local variables and fields in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, memory-management, field

I have the question listed above. **difference in array declaration and array memory allocation for local variables and fields in C#**

I am working on a WindowsForm application but I would like to declare some arrays.

In the *public partial class Form1 : Form*, I cannot declare an array and do the memory allocation separately (*if I do int[] numero = new int[5] it works*) but separately (in two steps) as  shown in the code below it does not.

When I hoop over the variable *numero* VS labels it as a **field**. I did the same in the derivative class *public Form1()* and it works fine in one step (int[] numero = new int[4]) and in two steps as shown below in the code. When I hoop over the variable *casinumero*, it labels it as a **local variable**. So the question is:

**WHY THE ARRAY DECLARATION AND MEMORY ALLOCATION CANNOT BE DONE IN ONE STEP FOR FIELDS AS IT IS FOR LOCAL VARIABLES?**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int [] numero;
        numero = new int[5];

        public Form1()
       {
            InitializeComponent();
            int[] casinumero;
            casinumero = new int[4];
       }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is worded incorrectly: *WHY THE ARRAY DECLARATION AND MEMORY ALLOCATION CANNOT BE DONE IN ONE STEP FOR FIELDS AS IT IS FOR LOCAL VARIABLES?*. It should be the other way around.

Comment: Your question makes very little sense. I'm afraid you may have tried to use some sort of machine-translation service to provide the English version. The question you ask is a non-question, because it asks why about something that isn't true. The "one step" initializer syntax is available for both fields and locals. It's the two-step initialization you show above that isn't legal, because program statements have to be inside methods. Even there, you _can_ initialize `numero` that way, as long as you move that statement into a method (e.g. the constructor).

Answer (score 0):

This is declaration:

```
public int [] numero;
```

Below is instantiation. Another way to word it: *This is using the variable.*. You are using the variable by assigning something to it or initializing it explicitly.

```
numero = new int[5];
```

You cannot use a variable at the class level.

From [C# Specs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables)

> An instance variable of a class comes into existence when a new instance of that class is created,

Therefore, you cannot use it before the instance is created.

You can declare it. If you do not initialize it, it will have a default initial value. Depending on the type, the default values vary. For reference type, as is the case with arrays, it will be initialized to `null`. This is called [definite assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables) and it is one of the C# rules.

You can do this, however (Please note inline comments):

```
public class Example
{
    // Declared here and it will be defaulted to null since we never
    // initialized it explicitly.
    public int[] numero;

    // Or we can initialize it and declare it in one step:
    // public int[] numero = new int[5];

    public Example()
    {
        // Now we are in the constructor, we can use the variable and 
        // explicitly initialize it.
        numero = new int[5];

        int[] casinumero;
        casinumero = new int[4];
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Or we can use it in a method
        numero = new int[5];
    }
}
```

Comment: `An instance variable of a class comes into existence when a new instance of that class is created,` this actually refers to accessing instance members in static contexts which is not permitted. actual reason is that this statement `numero = new int[5];` is only allowed within body of method, not at scope of class member declaration.